Issue with overriding glibc malloc using --wrap option in statically linked application after glibc upgrade
After upgrading to the latest glibc, I noticed that malloc_hooks is deprecated, so I am trying to override certain glibc functions with user-defined ones using the --wrap symbol. For instance, I'm using --wrap=malloc to override the glibc malloc function with my custom wrap_malloc.
Direct calls to malloc in my code are correctly redirected to wrap_malloc. However, when calling glibc functions like fopen(), which internally invokes malloc, the internal malloc call is not being overridden by my wrap_malloc.
Does anyone have suggestions on how I can solve this issue and ensure that internal malloc calls (e.g., from fopen()) are overridden with my custom function? Any insights would be appreciated!
I've tried using the LD_PRELOAD option, but it doesn't seem to work because my application is built statically
Update :
As suggested I attempted to implement a custom memory allocation approach by declaring malloc() and free() as weak attributes in glibc malloc.c file:
//malloc.c
void free(void *mem) __attribute__((weak));
void* malloc(size_t size) __attribute__((weak));

also in the definition ,I defined it as follows: as malloc() is aliased to __libc_malloc
void* __attribute__((weak)) __libc_malloc(size_t bytes) {
    // code
}

However, I added debug prints to my custom malloc and free to test, but I don't see those prints, indicating that calls to malloc are not invoking my custom implementation.
the compilation command to build my application, looks like this:
$(CXX) -Wl,--verbose -o $@ -I$(SSL_NOTHREADS_INCDIR) -L$(SSL_NOTHREADS_LIBDIR) `sn-linktool $+` $(NPU_IXP_LIBS) $(NP4C_NLM11K_LIBS) $(BOXER_STATIC_LIBS) -lsn_memacct -lm -ldl -ltirpc -lssp -lc -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition $(STATIC_NSS_LIBS_CXX)

In this command, my custom malloc is part of libsn_memacct.a, which is linked with -lsn_memacct, while malloc.c from glibc is linked through -lc. Even though I defined glibc's malloc as a weak symbol, it seems my custom malloc is not overriding it.

For fully-static linking, your best (and likely only) choice is to replace the entire libc.a(malloc.o) with an alternate implementation.
Note that you must replace all the symbols in malloc.o, or your link will fail with multiply-defined symbols.
For example, on Fedora 40, the following "works":
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static char buf[10000] __attribute__((aligned(16)));
static char *mptr = &buf[0];

void *malloc(size_t sz)
{
  char *r = mptr;
  mptr += (sz + 0xF) & ~0xF;
  fprintf(stderr, "malloc(%zu) -> %p\n", sz, r);
  return r;
}

void free(void *p)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "free(%p)\n", p);
}

void *calloc(size_t nelem, size_t sz)
{
  void *r = malloc(nelem * sz);
  fprintf(stderr, "calloc(%zu, %zu) -> %p\n", nelem, sz, r);
  return r;
}

void *realloc(void *p, size_t sz)
{
  char *r = malloc(sz);
  memcpy(r, p, sz);
  fprintf(stderr, "realloc(%p, %zu) -> %p\n", p, sz, r);
  return r;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  fprintf(stderr, "  main starts\n");
  if (argc < 2) return 0;
  fprintf(stderr, "  fopen(%s)\n", argv[1]);
  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "w");
  fprintf(stderr, "  fopen(%s) -> %p\n", argv[1], fp);

  if (fp == NULL) return 1;


  fprintf(stderr, "  fclose(%p)\n", fp);
  fclose(fp);

  fprintf(stderr, "  main returns\n");
  return 0;
}

gcc -Wall -Wextra -static t.c && ./a.out foo.txt
malloc(6) -> 0x49d1b0
malloc(1241) -> 0x49d1c0
calloc(1241, 1) -> 0x49d1c0
malloc(24) -> 0x49d6a0
malloc(160) -> 0x49d6c0
malloc(160) -> 0x49d760
malloc(256) -> 0x49d800
malloc(256) -> 0x49d900
  main starts
  fopen(foo.txt)
malloc(472) -> 0x49da00
  fopen(foo.txt) -> 0x49da00
  fclose(0x49da00)
free(0x49da00)
  main returns
free(0x49d900)
free(0x49d800)

Above you can clearly see malloc being called from fopen and free being called from fclose.
Update:

In my wrap_malloc function, after handling some memory accounting, I want to call the original malloc using __real_malloc.

In that case the solution above will not work. But you can make it work by doing this:

extract malloc.o from libc.a: ar x /path/to/libc.a malloc.o
weaken{malloc,calloc,realloc,free} in the extracted object:

cat > to-weaken <<EOF
malloc
realloc
calloc
free
EOF

objcopy --weaken-symbols=to-weaken malloc.o malloc2.o


when you want to call the originalmalloc, use its __malloc alias.
link with the malloc2.o object.

Here it is all together:
#include <stdio.h>

extern void *__malloc(size_t),
            *__realloc(void *p, size_t),
            *__calloc(size_t, size_t);
extern void __free(void*);

void *malloc(size_t sz)
{
  void *r = __malloc(sz);
  fprintf(stderr, "malloc(%zu) -> %p\n", sz, r);
  return r;
}

void free(void *p)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "free(%p)\n", p);
  __free(p);
}

void *calloc(size_t nelem, size_t sz)
{
  void *r = __calloc(nelem, sz);
  fprintf(stderr, "calloc(%zu, %zu) -> %p\n", nelem, sz, r);
  return r;
}

void *realloc(void *p, size_t sz)
{
  char *r = __realloc(p, sz);
  fprintf(stderr, "realloc(%p, %zu) -> %p\n", p, sz, r);
  return r;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  fprintf(stderr, "  main starts\n");
  if (argc < 2) return 0;
  fprintf(stderr, "  fopen(%s)\n", argv[1]);
  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "w");
  fprintf(stderr, "  fopen(%s) -> %p\n", argv[1], fp);

  if (fp == NULL) return 1;


  fprintf(stderr, "  fclose(%p)\n", fp);
  fclose(fp);

  fprintf(stderr, "  main returns\n");
  return 0;
}

gcc -Wall -Wextra -static t.c malloc2.o && ./a.out foo.txt

malloc(6) -> 0x1279fa0
calloc(1241, 1) -> 0x1279fc0
malloc(24) -> 0x127a4b0
malloc(160) -> 0x127a4d0
malloc(160) -> 0x127a580
malloc(256) -> 0x127a630
malloc(256) -> 0x127a740
  main starts
  fopen(foo.txt)
malloc(472) -> 0x127a850
  fopen(foo.txt) -> 0x127a850
  fclose(0x127a850)
free(0x127a850)
  main returns
free(0x127a740)
free(0x127a630)


Thanks for your reply!
In my wrap_malloc function, after handling some memory accounting, I want to call the original malloc using __real_malloc. If I replace the glibc malloc.o with my custom implementation, how would this work? I still need to retain the glibc malloc implementation as well.
Could you please advise on how to achieve this while replacing malloc.o but also retaining the original glibc malloc?

@BhavyaM I've updated the answer.

I tried the approach you suggested and made updates to my question. Please take a look.

@BhavyaM You did the opposite of what I suggested. You want your malloc to be a strong symbol, and you want the libc.a(malloc.o) to become weak.

yes, __libc_malloc is also from the malloc.o , i said glibc malloc is aliased to __libc_malloc, so i added weak symbok in the definition also..  i have not posted my custom malloc implementation code.. my custom malloc is in file called memacct.c , there i have not declared it as weak

Apologies for the confusion. I retested, and now I see my custom malloc function is being invoked. Thanks for the suggestion—it worked!

@BhavyaM If the answer helped you, upvote it. If it resolved your question, accept it. We work for browny points here.
